# Conditional Count On Row_Number

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a query that calculates the number working days within a month based on a table which stores all our public holidays.

The current output would show all working days, excluding public holidays and Saturday and Sunday, I would like to show each day of the month, but don't increment on a public holiday or Saturday or Sunday.

Is there a way to conditionally increment the row number?

Query is below:

```
DECLARE @startnum INT=0
DECLARE @endnum INT=365;

WITH gen AS 
(
    SELECT @startnum AS num
    UNION ALL
    SELECT num + 1 
    FROM gen 
    WHERE num + 1 <= @endnum   
)
, holidays AS
( 
    SELECT CONVERT(DATE, transdate)  AS HolidayDate 
    FROM WORKCALENDER w  
    WHERE w.CALENDARID = 'PubHoliday'
)
, allDays AS
( 
    SELECT DATEADD( d, num, CONVERT( DATE, '1 Jan 2016' ) ) AS DateOfYear
    , DATENAME( dw, DATEADD( d, num, CONVERT( DATE, '1 Jan 2016' ))) AS [dayOfWeek]
    FROM gen 
)
select number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY DateOfYear  )     
, *
from allDays
    LEFT OUTER JOIN holidays
        ON allDays.DateOfYear = holidays.HolidayDate
WHERE holidays.HolidayDate IS NULL
    AND allDays.dayOfWeek NOT IN ( 'Saturday', 'Sunday')
    AND DateOfYear >= CONVERT( DATE, '1 ' + DATENAME( MONTH, GETDATE() ) + ' 2016' )
    AND DateOfYear < CONVERT( DATE, '1 ' + DATENAME( MONTH, DATEADD( month, 1, GETDATE()) ) + ' 2016' )
option (maxrecursion 10000)
```

Comment: Some formatting would do wonders to this wall of text. I formatted this so I could read it and it is far less confusing. FWIW, you should look into using a tally or numbers table instead a recursive cte for counting. To solve the problem at hand you need to provide a little bit more detail. Most likely a cte with only the dates you want to have a count which would be left joined to the list of all dates.

Comment: Yes I think you just need to put your existing final select (minus the row number bit) into another cte, then select from this filtered cte, adding the row number)

Answer (score 0):

kind of pseudo code

```
select date, row_number() over (order by date) as num  
from  ( select date 
        from allDates 
        where month = x and weekday  
        exept 
        select date 
        from holidays 
        where month is x 
      ) as t
union all
select date, null
from holidays 
where month is x  
order by date
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a windowed sum, see how the output of WorkdaySequenceInMonth is composed.

```
DECLARE   @startDate  DATE = '20160101'
        , @numDays    INT =  365
        , @num        INT  =  0;

DECLARE @Holidays TABLE (Holiday DATE);

INSERT INTO @Holidays(Holiday)
     VALUES ('20160101')
          , ('20160115')
          , ('20160714');

WITH nums AS
(
    SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY object_id) - 1 as num
    FROM sys.columns
),
dateRange as
(
  SELECT 
      DATEADD(DAY, num, @startDate) AS Dt
    , num
  FROM nums
  WHERE num < @numDays
),
Parts AS
(
    SELECT
         R.Dt as [Date]
       , Year(R.Dt) as [Year]
       , Month(R.Dt) as [Month]
       , Day(R.Dt) as [Day]
       , Datename(weekday, R.Dt) as [Weekday]
       , CASE WHEN H.Holiday IS NOT NULL 
                   OR Datename(weekday, R.Dt) IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday')
              THEN 0
              ELSE 1
              END AS IsWorkday

    FROM dateRange R    
    LEFT JOIN @Holidays H ON R.Dt = H.Holiday
)
-- 
select 
    *   
    , sum(IsWorkday) over (PARTITION BY [Year],[month]
                           ORDER BY [Day]
                           ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as WorkdaySequenceInMonth      
from Parts
order by [Year], [Month]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can try this query, the initial part is the data generation, maybe you won't need it.
Then I generate a temp table with all the dates for the time period set in @StartYear, @EndYear
Then just simple queries to return the data

```
            -- generate holidays table
            select holiday 
            into #tempHolidays
            from
            (
            select '20160101' as holiday
            union all 
            select '20160201' as holiday
            union all 
            select '20160205' as holiday
            union all 
            select '20160301' as holiday
            union all 
            select '20160309' as holiday
            union all 
            select '20160315' as holiday
            )  as t


            create table #tempCalendar (Date_temp date)

            select * from 
            #tempHolidays

            declare @startYear int , @endYear int,  @i int,  @dateStart datetime , @dateEnd datetime,  @date datetime, @i = 0
            Select  @startYear = '2016'
                    ,@endYear = '2016'
                    ,@dateStart = (Select cast( (cast(@startYear as varchar(4)) +'0101') as datetime))
                    ,@dateEnd = (Select cast( (cast(@startYear as varchar(4)) +'1231') as datetime))
                    ,@date = @dateStart


                    --Insert dates of the period of time
            while (@date <> @dateEnd)
            begin

            insert into #tempCalendar
            Select @date
            set @date = (select DATEADD(dd,1,@date))

            end

            -- Retrive Date list
            Select Date_temp 
            from #tempCalendar
            where Date_temp not in (Select holiday from #tempHolidays)
            and datename(weekday,Date_temp) not in ('Saturday','Sunday')

            --REtrieve sum of working days per month
            select DATEPART(year,Date_temp) as year
                    ,DATEPART(month,Date_temp) as Month
                    ,Count(*) as CountOfWorkingDays

            from #tempCalendar
            where Date_temp not in (Select holiday from #tempHolidays)
            and datename(weekday,Date_temp) not in ('Saturday','Sunday')
            Group by DATEPART(year,Date_temp)
                    ,DATEPART(month,Date_temp)
```

You should change #tempHolidays for your Holidays table, and use @StarYear and @EndYear as your time period.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple demo that shows the use of the `partition by` clause to keep contiguity in your sequencing for non-holidays

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#dates') IS NOT null
    DROP TABLE #dates;
CREATE TABLE #dates (d DATE);

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#holidays') IS NOT null
    DROP TABLE #holidays;
CREATE TABLE #holidays (d DATE);

INSERT INTO [#holidays]
        ( [d] )
VALUES
    ('2016-12-25'),
    ('2017-12-25'),
    ('2018-12-25');

INSERT INTO [#dates]
        ( [d] )
SELECT TOP 1000 DATEADD(DAY, n, '2015-12-31')
FROM [Util].dbo.[Numbers] AS [n];


WITH holidays AS (
    SELECT d.*, CASE WHEN h.d IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS [IsHoliday]
    FROM [#dates] AS [d]
    LEFT JOIN [#holidays] AS [h]
        ON [d].[d] = [h].[d]
)
SELECT d, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [holidays].[IsHoliday] ORDER BY d)
FROM [holidays]
ORDER BY d;
```

And please forgive my marking only Christmas as a holiday!